# jQuery OOP element parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, javascript-objects

I want to create a jquery slider using oop. This is the structure of my code :

```
var photoGallery = new Slider();

function Slider(){ this.init(); }

Slider.prototype = {
  el : {
    nav : $('.slideshowNav', this.main),
    navItems  : $('.items', this.nav),
    main  : $('.slideshow')
  }
  ,init: function(){
    // some code here
  }//init

  // rest of functions here
}
```

My problem is that i have two `<div class="slideshow">` in same page and my code is wrong according to this situation.

I know that i can pass a parameter to `init()` and all my problems will fly away, but i use the `this.el` elements also in other functions so this is not a solution.

I want to know how i can add another element to `this.el` coming from `Slider()` parameter (I know, there is no parameter now)

Or, does somebody has an idea how i can make the structure which looks like

```
$('.slideshow').each(...)
```

?

I need my code working with multiple elements on a single page

Comment: Do you want multiple `Slider` instances, one for each element on the page, or one instance for all elements?

Comment: Move methods and variables out of the prototype and into the constructor if you need them to be different for individual instances.

Comment: I want multiple Slider instances :). Thanks for translating my problem in a easy way :)

Comment: You'll want to use the [jQuery UI widget factory](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how many [jquery plugins](https://github.com/Ralt/multiple-select-auto-complete/blob/gh-pages/src/msac.jquery.js#L4-L8) start:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(opts) {
    // Let each closure has its own options
    var myplugin = new Myplugin(opts);
    return this.each(myplugin);
};

function Myplugin(opts) {}
```

This way, people can call your code like this:

```
$('.slideshow').myplugin();
```

And each element will be handled separately. `this.el` will be able to be called easily in each of your instance with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (untested):

```
var galleries = [];

$('.slideshow').each(function(index, elem) {
    galleries.push(new Slider(elem));
});
```

And then change your `Slider` implementation to something like this:

```
function Slider(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.init(); 
}

Slider.prototype = {
    el : {
        nav : $('.slideshowNav', this.main),
        navItems  : $('.items', this.nav),
        main  : $('.slideshow')
    }
    ,init: function() {
        // some code here
    }//init

    // rest of functions here
}
```

The new thing with this approach is, that you have a `this.elem` inside your `Slider` instance which you can refer to. You will have to adapt some of your code to refer to `this.elem` inside your `Slider` prototype to work, but this should get you started.

Comment: This is what i tried but i want to use this.elem into `el` object

Comment: What do you mean by "use this.elem into el object"?

Comment: I need somethingh like `el : {
    main : this.elem,
    nav : $('.slideshowNav', this.main) }`

Comment: When i check console.log i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: But `el` is bound to the `prototype` of your Object, so its the same for all instances. This will not work unless you overwrite it for example inside the `init` function for every instance... but then again it would be useless in the prototype.

Comment: Do you have another idea how i can rewrite my code to work with multiple instances?

Comment: You can try implementing this as a jQuery plugin or widget as others already pointed out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30620/discussion-between-stefanz-and-migg)